# python - How to put the input from an Entrybox to a label in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.3

I am trying to put the information submitted into the data entry box into a label of my canvas. So far all I get on the label is this.

```
PY_VAR#
```

This is my current code.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
font = ("Times New Roman", 5)
font2 = ("Times New Roman", 10) 
font3 = ("Times New Roman", 15)
def getData():
       1a.get()
       2a.get()
       test()

def enterData():
       global 1a, 2a
       canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
       box1 = Entry(textvariable = 1a).place(x=100, y=200)
       box2 = Entry(textvariable = 2a).place(x=300, y=200)
       Button(text = "enter data", font = font2, command = getData).place(x=560, y=100)

def test():
        global 1a, 2a
        1a = StringVar()
        2a = StringVar()
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
        canvas.pack()

        Label(root, text = 1a, font = font3).place(x=70,  y=400)
enterData()
```

I've also tried seeing what 1a and 2a is assigned to, it is always PY_VAR#.

**Could anyone see what is wrong with my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to create new `StringVar`s every time you click the button, so move the creation of those to the top, and rename them - you can't start a variable with a number (don't forget to change the reference to `1a` and `2a` in the `enterData` function too):

```
#  import tkinter    You shouldn't import tkinter in two different ways - get rid of this one...
from tkinter import *
font = ("Times New Roman", 5)
font2 = ("Times New Roman", 10) 
font3 = ("Times New Roman", 15)

stringVar1a = StringVar()
stringVar2a = StringVar()
```

Second, the `1a.get()` and `2a.get()` lines do nothing - they get the contents of the entry, but nothing is done with them.  So really you don't need a separate `getData` and `test` functions, but for the sake of preserving your structure, I'll leave them:

```
def getData():
    test()
```

Third, when you create the label, you don't want to set its text attribute to the `StringVar`, you want to set the *textvariable* attribute to the `StringVar`:

```
Label(root, textvariable = stringVar1a, font = font3).place(x=70,  y=400)
```

Comment: If you set the `textvariable` attribute to the `stringVar1a` it will constantly stay updated.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the `text` parameter of your `Label` to the *variable* `1a`, not the *content*. Use this instead:

```
Label(root, text=1a.get())
```

But I have to say, this code is a bit ridiculous. `1a` and `2a` can't even be variables, `place()` is often enough a bad idea for creating GUIs, you're doing unnecessary operations (the function `getData` is completely obsolete) and you're always creating new labels.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my code is a mess because I'm a bit of a noob. Sorry.